# tslint spitting out cyclomatic complexity error

Tags: angular, tslint

On my angular 8 project with

```
"codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~5.19.0",
```

After running :

```
ng lint myapp --fix=true
```

I get :

```
ERROR: ...html:428:106 - The cyclomatic complexity exceeded the defined limit (cost '5'). Your template should be refactored.
```

even though in my `tslint.js` I set :

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": ["node_modules/codelyzer"],
  "rules": {
    "template-i18n": false,
    "cyclomatic-complexity": [true, 20],
```

Why is there this discrepancy between what I set in the settings ""cyclomatic-complexity": [true, 20]" and this error message I'm getting for many many files "(cost '5')"?

Also why is this happening at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template complexity is inside a different rule, namely:

```
"template-cyclomatic-complexity": [true, 6]
```

Source https://github.com/fulls1z3/angular-tslint-rules/issues/34

`"cyclomatic-complexity": [true, 20],` is for *.ts files